# How to handle expired url in gitmodules

Tags: git, git-submodules

I am encountering problems when working with git submodules.

In my case I'd like to check out some older commit, but the url given in .gitmodules has changed. Therefore git will exit with error.

```
Cloning into 'XXX'...
fatal: unable to access 'http://xxx: Could not resolve host: xxx
```

What is the most suitable workflow to conduct this?

Thanks, Daniel

Comment: So change the url?

Comment: @KamilCuk: I could check out the commit non-recursively and then manually fix the url in the submodule. But this would create a new commit in my .gitmodules. If I the go to another historic commit, I face the same problem. This very quickly becomes tedious, especially when there is sub-submodule, etc. How can I do this globally, once?

Comment: [`git config --global url.<base>.insteadOf`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-urlltbasegtinsteadOf), https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+url.insteadof

Comment: on a sidenote, always post the error message. It makes the post easier to search.